# Matching line endings ignores unicode characters

Tags: python, unicode, compare

I've got a small Python script that compares a word list imported from document A with a set of line endings in document B in order to copy the ones that don't match those rules to document C. Example:

```
A (word list): 
salir
entrar
leer

B (line endings list):
ir
ar

C (those from A that do not match B):
leer
```

In general it works fine but I realized that it doesn't work with line endings that contain a Unicode character as `ó` - there is no error message and everything seems smooth but the list C does still contain words ending with `ó`.

Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
inputobj = codecs.open(A, "r")
ruleobj = codecs.open(B, "r")
nomatch = codecs.open(C, "w")

inputtext = inputobj.readlines()
ruletext = ruleobj.readlines()

for line in inputtext:
    x = 0
    line = line.strip()
    for rule in ruletext:
        rule = rule.strip()
        if line.endswith(rule):
            print "rule", rule, " in line", line
            x= x+1
    if x == 0:
        nomatchlist.append(line)

for i in notmatchlist:
    print >> nomatch, i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried some code locally. It works well for the 'ó'.
Could you check the A & B are in the same encoding?

Comment: Thanks for your efford, B was indeed in another encoding!